# Display data in visio shape

Tags: visio

I'm reading the great book:
[Visualizing Information with Visio 2007](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/007148261X) in which I found there the following pivot shape:

[image: Pivot Table Data Shape]

My question is: 
How can I create a shape that can load data from a datarow of sometype of DB table:

[image: Data for the shapes in the drawing]

The org chart wizard can insert multiple data fields in the shape but not in a cool way the book presented...

Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

OK

It was easier than I thought...

When using the **data graphics** I can add text based on database fields or based on more advanced formulas.

1. Displaying row data is very easy and adjustable.
2. Positioning the information in the shape, is challenging: the real estate is limited by nature
   and predefined spots such as top middle, left right... can make design options, a problem.

For a Visio newbie, the data graphics are nothing less then amazing, nevertheless - too rigid.

Comment: Using formulas opens new design options. For example: concatenating "labels" and data fields- The task of making it look good is time consuming yet... Being able to display all the data needed is inportant.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably too late with a response, but here goes anyway:  I had a similar problem with too much data to display, and eventually opted to display the Shape Data window on the diagram page in addition to a core selection in the data graphic.  This allowed for a lot more clearly visibly displayed options.

Also, if you publish the diagram to SharePoint as a vdw file, the shape data can be displayed in the same way.  (This has made my client particularly happy!)